# Should I get the Blasphemer's Outfit or wait for Oathbreaker?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Doing a playthrough on Dark difficulty and I started gathering some diagrams for Blasphemer, then realized it may not be worth it. Upon checking some wikis, I see that there are two additional armor sets, but not much in terms of suggestions.

Should I wait on the Oathbreaker/Kingslayer set or get Blasphemer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I saved up my money and went straight for the Oathbreaker set.  The only important piece is the Draugir armor fragment which you can obtain in the intro scene of chapter 2.  You just have to make sure that you loot the Draugir before you finish off the rest of the enemies for your chance to get one.  That way, you can build the set as soon as you enter chapter 2 proper, and it'll be enough to carry you until you can get the Kingslayer set.

Chapter 1 on dark mode was easy enough (relatively speaking) that I didn't need the Blasphemer's outfit.